# Envers throws RuntimeException in ValidityAuditStrategy when no audit records (table partitioning)

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, hibernate-envers

In envers (`persistence.xml`), I enabled the strategy for table partitioning, according to the development guide: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/devguide/en-US/html/ch15.html#envers-partitioning

The class: **`ValidityAuditStrategy`**, throws `RuntimeException` when there is no audit record. This exception occurs when the Envers try to update an audit record with a date of final revision (revend_tstmp), but this audit record does not exist.

The database of my application receives data load from external applications and is not possible change these external applications to include their audit records.

I have no chance to handle this exception (I don't know how).

In method `ValidityAuditStrategy#updateLastRevision`:

```
if (l.size() == 1) {
  //... doStuff - OK
} else {
  throw new RuntimeException("Cannot find previous revision for entity " + auditedEntityName + " and id " + id);
}
```

In method `ValidityAuditStrategy#perform`:

```
if ( rowCount != 1 ) 
  throw new RuntimeException("Cannot update previous revision for entity " + auditedEntityName + " and id " + id);
```

A similar issue occurred in this link: https://developer.jboss.org/thread/160195?tstart=0 but had no solution.

It's possible apply a workaround?

I use **`hibernate-envers-4.1.3-Final`** version.

Log:

```
2015-07-17 10:23:28,653 DEBUG [-] [org.hibernate.SQL] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) update MY_ENTITY_AUD set ID_REV_FINAL=?, DATE_HOUR_REV_FINAL=? where ID_ENTITY=? and ID_REV <> ? and ID_REV_FINAL is null
2015-07-17 10:23:28,677 TRACE [-] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - 422
2015-07-17 10:23:28,677 TRACE [-] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) binding parameter [2] as [TIMESTAMP] - Thu Jul 17 10:23:28 BRT 2015
2015-07-17 10:23:28,677 TRACE [-] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) binding parameter [3] as [INTEGER] - 12345
2015-07-17 10:23:28,678 TRACE [-] [org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) binding parameter [4] as [INTEGER] - 422
2015-07-17 10:23:28,803 ERROR [-] [org.hibernate.AssertionFailure] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) HHH000099: an assertion failure occured (this may indicate a bug in Hibernate, but is more likely due to unsafe use of the session): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot update previous revision for entity my.package.MyEntity_AUD and id 12345
2015-07-17 10:23:28,841 WARN  [-] [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (http-/0.0.0.0:8080-5) ARJUNA012125: TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion - failed for SynchronizationImple< 0:ffffac1c045d:-3a5600e4:55a7c120:131, org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization@5619c5a3 >: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: Unable to perform beforeTransactionCompletion callback
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:754) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:338) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:490) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:114) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:53) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.resources.arjunacore.SynchronizationImple.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationImple.java:76)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.beforeCompletion(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:273)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.coordinator.TwoPhaseCoordinator.end(TwoPhaseCoordinator.java:93)
    at com.arjuna.ats.arjuna.AtomicAction.commit(AtomicAction.java:162)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.TransactionImple.commitAndDisassociate(TransactionImple.java:1189)
    at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.commit(BaseTransaction.java:126)
    at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.commit(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:75)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.endTransaction(CMTTxInterceptor.java:92) [jboss-as-ejb3-7.4.0.Final-redhat-19.jar:7.4.0.Final-redhat-19]
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot update previous revision for entity entity my.package.MyEntity_AUD and id 12345
    at org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy.perform(ValidityAuditStrategy.java:210) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.work.AbstractAuditWorkUnit.perform(AbstractAuditWorkUnit.java:76) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.executeInSession(AuditProcess.java:116) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcess.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcess.java:155) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.envers.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$1.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(AuditProcessManager.java:62) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:748) [hibernate-core-4.1.3-Final.jar:4.1.3-Final]
    ... 90 more
```

Answer (score 1):

In `persistence.xml` existing a property to specify a custom `AuditStrategey`: `org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy`.
Change,
From:

```
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy" value="org.hibernate.envers.strategy.ValidityAuditStrategy"/>
```

To:

```
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy" value="com.app.your.pack.YourCustomValidityAuditStrategy"/>
```

So now you can extend `ValidityAuditStrategy` and override `perform()` to not throw a `RuntimeException` when there is no previous revision for the entity, like this:

```
public class YourCustomValidityAuditStrategy extends ValidityAuditStrategy {

    private final Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Override
    public void perform(Session session, String entityName, AuditConfiguration auditCfg, Serializable id, Object data, Object revision) {
        try {
            super.perform(session, entityName, auditCfg, id, data, revision);           
        } catch (RuntimeException re) {
            if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
                logger.debug("IGNORE RuntimeException: Cannot update previous revision for entity.", re);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This will not work, the exception is throwing in a callback, you have to copy and paste the whole class, and change the throw exception to log or something.

Answer (score 1):

Overriding just the perform method and catching the RuntimeException won't help you as the code throwing the RuntimeException is enclosed in an anonymous class of type BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess and is executed later.

The ValidityAuditStrategy is not very flexible so the only solution i see is ugly but should work : you must copy the entire ValidityAuditStrategy code in a custom class and catch the RuntimeException in the BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess anonymous class. Then specify your custom class in the persistence.xml :

```
<property name="org.hibernate.envers.audit_strategy "value="com.app.xxx.CustomValidityAuditStrategy"/>
```

The perform() method should look like the following :

```
@Override
public void perform(
        final Session session,
        final String entityName,
        final EnversService enversService,
        final Serializable id,
        final Object data,
        final Object revision) {
    final AuditEntitiesConfiguration audEntitiesCfg = enversService.getAuditEntitiesConfiguration();
    final String auditedEntityName = audEntitiesCfg.getAuditEntityName( entityName );
    final String revisionInfoEntityName = enversService.getAuditEntitiesConfiguration().getRevisionInfoEntityName();

    // Save the audit data
    session.save( auditedEntityName, data );

    // Update the end date of the previous row.
    //
    // When application reuses identifiers of previously removed entities:
    // The UPDATE statement will no-op if an entity with a given identifier has been
    // inserted for the first time. But in case a deleted primary key value was
    // reused, this guarantees correct strategy behavior: exactly one row with
    // null end date exists for each identifier.
    final boolean reuseEntityIdentifier = enversService.getGlobalConfiguration().isAllowIdentifierReuse();
    if ( reuseEntityIdentifier || getRevisionType( enversService, data ) != RevisionType.ADD ) {
        // Register transaction completion process to guarantee execution of UPDATE statement after INSERT.
        ( (EventSource) session ).getActionQueue().registerProcess( new BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess() {
            @Override
            public void doBeforeTransactionCompletion(final SessionImplementor sessionImplementor) {
                final Queryable productionEntityQueryable = getQueryable( entityName, sessionImplementor );
                final Queryable rootProductionEntityQueryable = getQueryable(
                        productionEntityQueryable.getRootEntityName(), sessionImplementor
                );
                final Queryable auditedEntityQueryable = getQueryable( auditedEntityName, sessionImplementor );
                final Queryable rootAuditedEntityQueryable = getQueryable(
                        auditedEntityQueryable.getRootEntityName(), sessionImplementor
                );

                final String updateTableName;

                /*commented code*/
                ...

                /*comment the following piece of code*/
                /*if ( rowCount != 1 && ( !reuseEntityIdentifier || ( getRevisionType( enversService, data ) != RevisionType.ADD ) ) ) {
                    throw new RuntimeException(
                            "Cannot update previous revision for entity " + auditedEntityName + " and id " + id
                    );
                }*/
            }
        });
    }
    sessionCacheCleaner.scheduleAuditDataRemoval( session, data );
}
```

As i said its ugly...

Comment: I agree with you about not being flexible code. But in 4.2.14.Final version of Envers (my case), the `perform()` method is different and the exception is not thrown within an anonymous  class (the only anonymous class inside the method is `ReturningWork` and not `BeforeTransactionCompletionProcess`). In that version you can catch the exception.

Answer (score 1):

Setting org.hibernate.envers.allow_identifier_reuse: true helped in my scenario.

Comment: Welcome to SO Michael! Could you please add more details on were to set this and if possible why this solves the issue? Thanks!

Comment: Set this in application.yml in spring.jpa.properties. My scenario was that IDs were reused in AUD-tables which is not allowed by default. The error was the same, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly answers the original question, but on the outside looks the same: `Cannot update previous revision for entity my.package.MyEntity_AUD and id caa4ce8e`.

I am using hibernate-envers-5.4.1 and for whatever reason (probably some buggy import in the past) suddenly faced the same error.

Direct query to the database `select * from myentity_aud where id='caa4ce8e'` resulted in:

```
rev     revend  revtype id       ...
2121736 NULL    0       caa4ce8e ...
2121737 NULL    1       caa4ce8e ...
2121738 NULL    1       caa4ce8e ...
```

-- as seen, `revend` is `NULL` for all records.
The issue is: envers expects only one (the latest) to be `NULL`, all the rest must have the "overriding" `rev` to be set as `revend`.

So, to fix this particular case, it was enough to update to:

```
rev     revend  revtype id       ...
2121736 2121737 0       caa4ce8e ...
2121737 2121738 1       caa4ce8e ...
2121738 NULL    1       caa4ce8e ...
```

and after that everything worked like a charm.

However, if you have millions of such records, you may want to write some script which will take care of them automatically.